# can we migrate a code repository from one AWS account to another aws account using CLI. if not is there any way to do that?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, aws-codecommit

I want to migrate a code from one AWS account to another AWS account using code commit CLI.
Can anyone have any idea or any documents on "How to".

can we also clone a repo to another aws account?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since CodeCommit is just a regular Git repository, you can create a new repository in the target account, checkout the source repository locally and push it to the newly created repository.

There is no native way to move, clone or transfer ownership of a CodeCommit repository.